# Did the transmeta processor architecture work by binary translation?

Tags: chip, binary-translation

[Transmeta Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmeta) produced the [Transmeta Crusoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmeta_Crusoe) Processor architecture. (Transmeta was also famous for [having Linus Torvalds work there](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2003/06/17/linus_torvalds_leaves_transmeta/) at the time.)

We can see from the wikipedia article that the Crusoe processor appears to implements [Code Morphing Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Morphing_Software).  This gives it the ability in theory to [execute instructions from other architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmeta_Crusoe). (eg RISC or Java VM instructions.)

We see a similar pattern in Apple's MacOS [Rosetta binary translation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)). This enabled software binaries compiled for PowerPC to continue running on the new x86 architecture.

My question is: **Did the transmeta processor architecture work by [binary translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation#Dynamic_binary_translation)?**

Comment: Started reading Wikipedia article you refer to, and see: "Code Morphing Software consisted of an interpreter, a runtime system and a dynamic binary translator.". Isn't it an answer to your question?

Comment: You could argue those components add up to a virtual machine not a translator. This is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the Wikipedia article on [Transmeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmeta#Code_Morphing_Software) there's a good example for the Code Morphing process, taken from a [PDF document](https://web.archive.org/web/20010602205826/http://www.transmeta.com:80/crusoe/download/pdf/crusoetechwp.pdf) (Wayback archived) with even more details:

> The operation of Transmeta's code morphing software is similar to the final optimization pass of a conventional compiler. Considering a fragment of 32-bit x86 code:
>
> ```
> add eax,dword ptr [esp] // load data from stack, add to eax
> add ebx,dword ptr [esp] // ditto, for ebx
> mov esi,[ebp]           // load esi from memory
> sub ecx,5               // subtract 5 from ecx register
> ```
>
> This is first converted simplistically into native instructions:
>
> ```
> ld %r30,[%esp]       // load from stack, into temporary
> add.c %eax,%eax,%r30 // add to %eax, set condition codes.
> ld %r31,[%esp]
> add.c %ebx,%ebx,%r31
> ld %esi,[%ebp]
> sub.c %ecx,%ecx,5
> ```
>
> The optimizer then eliminates common sub-expressions and unnecessary condition code operations and, potentially, applies other optimizations such as loop unrolling:
>
> ```
> ld %r30,[%esp]     // load from stack only once
> add %eax,%eax,%r30
> add %ebx,%ebx,%r30 // reuse data loaded earlier
> ld %esi,[%ebp]
> sub.c %ecx,%ecx,5  // only this last condition code needed
> ```
>
> Finally, the optimizer groups individual instructions ("atoms") into long instruction words ("molecules") for the underlying hardware:
>
> ```
> ld %r30,[%esp];  sub.c %ecx,%ecx,5
> ld %esi,[%ebp];  add %eax,%eax,%r30;  add %ebx,%ebx,%r30
> ```
>
> These two VLIW molecules could potentially execute in fewer cycles than the original instructions could on an x86 processor.

So it indeed translates the x86 binary code into the native VLIW binary code. You can call this "binary translation", and it's not an "interpreter", and it's not a "virtual machine" (though this notion is a bit fuzzy; a virtual machine can use various methods to execute actual code, including translating it).

Also note that modern x86 CPUs all use a similar scheme: They translate x86 binary into a more simple, RISC-like code, and then schedule and execute it.

Comment: It's not just "modern" x86 processors which do such translation; the contemporaries of the Crusoe already did it.

Comment: @MSalters: Which contemporaries do you mean exactly? "Modern" x86 CPU to quite a bit of translating and rescheduling, just like the optimization on the Transmeta shown above. I'm not aware other CPUs did that at the time of the Crusoe, so if any did, I'd be extremely curious.

Comment: AMD's K6 and Athlon, as well as Intel's Pentium 2 and 3 all translated x86 into a RISC-like internal representation. Rescheduling or Out-of-Order execution came with the original Pentium.

Comment: @MSalters Sure, they (in fact the K5 before) do translate a single X86 into one or more (up to 4 for K5) internal opcodes, and _may_ rechedule them. But this is a strict linear process within the CPU to better utilize seperate function unit. The code gets neither optimised, nor rearaged (beside using different function units) and most of all, not writen back into memory to be executed from there in all subsequent execution. So far, not even modern CPUs do so - caching the intermediate format is the maximum that is done.

Comment: A big difference between "Code Morphing" and the translation of instructions into micro-ops that x86 CPUs do, is that the former is something done in software, while the later is something that gets done in hardware. There's nothing like common sub-expression elimination optimizations being done in x86 CPUs.

Comment: @MSalters The Pentium (P5) CPUs were superscaler (two pipelines) but in-order.  The Pentium Pro (P6) CPUs were the first out-of-order x86 CPUs.

Answer (score 6):

From a comment:

> You could argue those components add up to a virtual machine not a translator.

A virtual machine IS a translator. The virtual ISA is translated to run on the physical ISA. The only real distinction is whether and for how long the translations are saved for reuse.

Any microcoded CPU is a virtual machine, in which every instruction is translated on the fly ("interpreted") every time it is encountered — there is no attempt to reuse the translation.

I once worked on the design of a machine (in the early 1980s) that did the translation (from a zero-address "stack machine" ISA to a three-address RISC ISA) when moving instructions from main memory to the instruction cache. As long as the cache line was not replaced, the translation could be reused.

IIRC, the Transmeta actually writes the translations out to a separate area of main memory, allowing them to persist indefinitely. The translation is done by software, rather than hardware, and as long as the original executable file is not modified, the translation can be reused.

Comment: Agreed. I would argue that code execution (interpretation / binary translation / native code virtualization) is just one property of a VM. Typical VMs also define memory, manage threads, control access to storage, and so on, so BT is not in and of itself enough to qualify something as a virtual machine. FWIW, the two engineers who wrote the original just-in-time compiler for Android's Dalvik VM previously worked at Transmeta.